Insert data if not exists from default trace SQL server
I am trying to capture DDL changes from default trace. I wanted to schedule it to agent job
but the data getting inserted as duplicate. I want to insert only new data changes.
Here is sample which I have tried it
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Default_trace_DDL_Capture](
    [HostName] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [ApplicationName] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [NTUserName] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [NTDomainName] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [LoginName] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [SPID] [int] NULL,
    [EventClass] [int] NULL,
    [EventName] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
    [EventSubClass] [int] NULL,
    [TEXTData] [ntext] NULL,
    [StartTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [EndTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [ObjectName] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [DatabaseName] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [FileName] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [IsSystem] [int] NULL
)

DECLARE @filename VARCHAR(255) 
SELECT @FileName = SUBSTRING(path, 0, LEN(path)-CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(path))+1) + '\Log.trc'  
FROM sys.traces   
WHERE is_default = 1;  



WITH CTE_InsertValues AS

(
SELECT gt.HostName, 
       gt.ApplicationName, 
       gt.NTUserName, 
       gt.NTDomainName, 
       gt.LoginName, 
      gt.SPID, 
       gt.EventClass, 
       te.Name AS EventName,
      gt.EventSubClass,      
      gt.TEXTData, 
       gt.StartTime, 
       gt.EndTime, 
       gt.ObjectName, 
       gt.DatabaseName, 
       gt.FileName, 
       gt.IsSystem
FROM [fn_trace_gettable](@filename, DEFAULT) gt 
JOIN sys.trace_events te ON gt.EventClass = te.trace_event_id 

where EventClass in (46,47,164)
and objectname not like '_WA_Sys_%'
and objectname not in ('telemetry_xevents')

)
insert into tbl_Default_trace_DDL_Capture
select
c.HostName, 
c.ApplicationName, 
c.NTUserName, 
c.NTDomainName, 
c.LoginName, 
c.SPID, 
c.EventClass, 
c.EventName,
c.EventSubClass,
c.TEXTData, 
c.StartTime, 
c.EndTime, 
c.ObjectName, 
c.DatabaseName, 
c.FileName, 
c.IsSystem
FROM CTE_InsertValues c

LEFT JOIN tbl_Default_trace_DDL_Capture

t ON c.DatabaseName = t.DatabaseName and c.Objectname = t.Objectname 
and c.Eventname=t.Eventname and c.Starttime=t.Starttime
;

Using not exists
Updated : As per ErikReasonableRatesDarling suggestion
insert into  tbl_Default_trace_DDL_Capture 

SELECT 
      gt.HostName, 
       gt.ApplicationName, 
       gt.NTUserName, 
       gt.NTDomainName, 
       gt.LoginName, 
      gt.SPID, 
       gt.EventClass, 
       te.Name AS EventName,
      gt.EventSubClass,      
      gt.TEXTData, 
       gt.StartTime, 
       gt.EndTime, 
       gt.ObjectName, 
       gt.DatabaseName, 
       gt.FileName, 
       gt.IsSystem
       ,getdate() AS upload_date
FROM [fn_trace_gettable]('C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\Log.trc', DEFAULT) gt 
JOIN sys.trace_events te ON gt.EventClass = te.trace_event_id 

where EventClass in (46,47,164)
and objectname not like '_WA_Sys_%'
and objectname not in ('telemetry_xevents')

and NOT EXISTS (
select * from tbl_Default_trace_DDL_Capture A where gt.objectname =a.objectname
and gt.DatabaseName=a.DatabaseName
)

Thank you.

@ErikReasonableRatesDarling  Thanks I have used IF EXISTS and it is working now.
